# Error adding app to an internal SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created an app using VS2013's convert to SharePoint feature. I have tried adding the app in two ways namely Provider hosted and SharePoint hosted, both of which return an error.

I want the app to be internal so I believe it needs to be SharePoint hosted which returns the following error in Visual Studio:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'install app for SharePoint': There were errors when validating the App Package

Alternatively, when the app is Provider hosted I can upload it to SharePoint but I get the following error when I try to add it:

> The specified application identifier * is invalid or does not exist

Does anyone know how I can solve either of these issues?

Cheers for any help

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is this convert to SharePoint feature? What was converted?

Comment: I converted an asp project into a SharePoint app, its a new feature added to visual studio 2013. More information can be found here: http://aymanelhattab.com/2014/01/11/converting-asp-net-web-applications-into-sharepoint-apps-using-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Is C# involved?

Comment: Yeah the project is c# based I believe. It was written by another dev team, using ASP, C# and JavaScript

Comment: Ah, SharePoint-hosted apps cannot contain C#, which is why it's not validating.  It will have to be converted to JS to be published as a SharePoint-hosted app.  If you want to use a provider-hosted app, you must register the app as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860570.aspx).

Comment: Oh right, that is unfortunate. Thank you for the help, do you know a quick way of converting C# to JS?